# Как вывести в модальном окне нажатое изображение?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="gallery" class="container-fluid">
            <img src="/images/landscaping.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div id="myModal" class="modal"">
            
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не ясно с какой проблемой вы столкнулись. Добавьте обработчики клика для изображений. Добавьте тэг img в модальное окно. При клике получите src нажатого, и впишите его в src модального. Отобразите модальное.

```
$("#gallery img").click(function(){
    $("#target-img").attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    $("#modal").show();
});
```